# Need help optimizing a simple query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

Let's say I have the following query:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(id) numRows, 
  SUM(value) totSum 
FROM someTable
WHERE foo= @bar
```

Simple enough. It sums all values where the column foo equals to the passed parameter, and counts how many rows were involved in the sum.
Now, in my program I have some logic that evaluates the value only if the resultant count is below, let's say, 4.

I want to optimize the query so that I would get an empty result set if count was above 4. 
My first idea was to slap another condition on the query (where numRows < 4), but that wouldn't work because numRows isn't a column defined in someTable.
My second idea was to make the query a subquery, and then filter the results through the subquery's table, like so:

```
SELECT
 *
 FROM (
   SELECT
     COUNT(id) numRows, 
     SUM(value) totSum 
   FROM someTable
   WHERE foo= @bar
 ) subQuery
where subQuery.numRows < 4
```

My main question with this solution is whether or not the subquery will be completely computed, or if the main query halts it as soon as numRows hits 4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just add this to your original query. Definitely more easy-to-read and probably (not sure) better performance.

```
HAVING COUNT(ID) < 4
```

Comment: It will have exactly the same execution plan and as such, exactly the same performance. But yes, it is easier to read.

Comment: Thanks. I tend to overlook the "having" clause often... i should read more about it.